# Origin of the Breadth-First Search algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, math-history

I'd like to know about the history of the breadth-first search algorithm. Can anyone point me to its inventor?

It appears that the *depth*-first search algorithm is attributed to a man named Charles Pierre Tremaux, but a google search for "inventor/history of breadth-first search" yields no fruit.

Perhaps it was first formally laid out by someone who did a great deal of more important work in graph theory and algorithm design? (Turing? Dijkstra?)

Comment: Pretty sure the first BFS algorithm was neanderthals zigzagging to find animal trails.

Comment: @DanielV Doubtful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following remarks are found in the end chapter notes to Chapter 22, Elementary Graph Algorithms of Corman, et al., *[Introduction to Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072970545)*, 2nd. ed., MIT Press, 2001, on page 560:

> *Breadth-first search was discovered by Moore [226] in the context of finding paths through mazes. Lee [198] independently discovered the same algorithm in the context of routing wires on circuit boards.*

The relevant references are:

E. F. Moore (1959), The shortest path through a maze. In *Proceedings of the International Symposium on the Theory of Switching*, Harvard University Press, pp. 285–292.

C. Y. Lee (1961), [An algorithm for path connection and its applications](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TEC.1961.5219222). *IRE Transactions on Electronic Computers*, EC-10(3), pp. 346–365.

---

Interestingly, the chapter notes give no such specific references for the depth-first search, noting only that it was well-known and widely used in the 1950s.